# Define header height

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header, area

I must modify the height of this heading, the white part as seen in the photo:
https://www.girodolares.cl/

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1lks.png)

It is a wordpress template and I know it measures 1263x102, but I cannot find the path to modify it. Can you guide me how to find it? Which file to modify?

I have tried some CSS code but it did not work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height with this selector:

```
.main-header-area {
    background: #fff;
    height: 150px; /* or what ever height you need */
}
```

It looks like it's in .../wp-content/themes/viktor/style.css line #2060

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to do that but it works for me only to expand (height: 450px for example) but not to reduce. Maybe some other value is limiting the ability to reduce the header?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. By default the overall height of the header is being controlled by the collective margins and padding of it's child elements. Try adjusting the padding on `.main-header-area .logo-area` and `.main-header-area .main-menu ul li` and `.main-header-area .search-area` and see if that helps to get you the height you're looking for.

Comment: If you tweak the padding on those child elements, then you shouldn't need to specifically set the height of `.main-header-area`... unless you want to